# JAVA AND OR and IF

Tags: java, if-statement

basically what needs to happen is that it needs to check what the type of Champion is, and compare it to challenges to see if it can actually do that challenge, its quite hard to explain...
a wizard can fight "magic" and "mystery"
a warrior can fight "fight" and "mystery"
a dragon can fight "fight" and "mystery(only if the dragon talks)"

what I have come up with is this...

```
public boolean canFight(String nme, int id)
{
    Challenge chal = getChallengeObj(id);
    Champion champ = getChampionObj(nme.toLowerCase());

    if(champ.getType().equals("wizard") && (chal.getTypeAsString().equals("magic") || chal.getTypeAsString().equals("fight"))) {
        return true;
    } else if(champ.getType().equals("warrior") && (chal.getTypeAsString().equals("fight") || chal.getTypeAsString().equals("mystery"))) {
        return true;
    } else if((champ.getType().equals("dragon") || champ.getType().equals("dragon") && champ.isMystery()) && (chal.getTypeAsString().equals("fight") || chal.getTypeAsString().equals("magic"))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I thank anyone who has a go at helping me, I am open to any response, even complaints on how complicated the code is!!

(It is checking everything toLowerCase() btw, just in case this isnt clear in the code, as it is in the methods that are called in different classes.

THANKS!!

EDIT

The problem is is that it keeps returning false, and I am a second year university student, so if you could give examples of what you mean by your answers, that would be greatly appreciated :) 
Thanks again

Comment: You should look into switch statements

Comment: Side Note: It would be better to create constants for `"wizard"`, `"magic"`, `"warrior"`, `"fight"`, and `"mystery"`

Comment: Or `enum`s. That would be better still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get different behaviour from different types in Java is using [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) - basically, put a virtual method into your Champion type with different implementations in Wizard, Warrior, Dragon etc subtypes

A chain of if-else's based on the type of an object is a bit of an anti-pattern in Java - crying out to be refactored into a single call to a virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a 2D array to map FightCompatilibity between Challenge and Champ. Model each Champ and Challenge as enum. Maybe, take a look at [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly something, which should be done by class hiearchy. Like if you know, someone is Wizard, you should already known what he can attack or not, therefore you should move responsibility into that Wizard class instead of testing it externally.

I did an example with 4 classes :

In this enum are listed all attack types

```
public enum AttackTypes {
    Magic, Meele, Ranged;
}
```

---

This is abstract class, it only helps you define behaviour that is same for all classes. I supposed that every class has some subset of "attack types" (or something similar). In my example, I just suppose, that each class can fight only against some types of attack. In constructor, I get all the attack I can fight and then I can chack it with this canAttack.

```
public abstract class Champion {
    private List<AttackTypes> attackTo;

    public Champion(AttackTypes... attack) {
        this.attackTo = new ArrayList<>();
        this.attackTo.addAll(Arrays.asList(attack));
    }        

    public boolean canAttack(AttackTypes attackType){
        for (AttackTypes attack : attackTo){
            if (attack == attackType){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

---

This is simple Warrior class, in my example, it can fight only Magic and Meele :

```
public class Warrior extends Champion{
    public Warrior(){
        super(AttackTypes.Magic, AttackTypes.Meele);
    }    
}
```

---

And similar to Warrior, here is Wizard :

```
public class Wizard extends Champion{

    public Wizard(){
        super(AttackTypes.Ranged, AttackTypes.Magic);
    }
}
```

---

This approach is important, because it is extremely easy to add new class (like Ranger for example). You just add him and thats all, you dont have to anything in your already finished code.

---

Then you can use it as following :

```
    Champion wizard = new Wizard();
    Champion warrior = new Warrior();
    AttackTypes attackType = AttackTypes.Ranged;

    System.out.println("can wizard attack? : " + wizard.canAttack(attackType));
    System.out.println("can warrior attack? : " + warrior.canAttack(attackType));
```

This having this output :

```
can wizard attack? : true
can warrior attack? : false
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more flexible approach would be to use a pair of `enum`s. Something like this would be a good start. I haven't exactly implemented your logic because there is a flaw in it:

```
enum Champion {

    Wizard(EnumSet.of(Challenge.Fight, Challenge.Magic)),
    Warrior(EnumSet.of(Challenge.Fight, Challenge.Mystery)),
    Dragon(EnumSet.of(Challenge.Fight, Challenge.Magic)) {
                @Override
                public boolean canFight(Champion enemy, Challenge attack) {
                    // For demonstration.
                    return susceptible.contains(attack) && enemy == Champion.Dragon;
                }
            };

    protected final Set<Challenge> susceptible;

    Champion(Set<Challenge> susceptible) {
        this.susceptible = susceptible;
    }

    public boolean canFight(Champion enemy, Challenge attack) {
        return susceptible.contains(attack);
    }
}

enum Challenge {

    Magic,
    Fight,
    Mystery;
}
```

You flaw is in `(champ.getType().equals("dragon") || champ.getType().equals("dragon") && champ.isMystery())` which doesn't make sense.